# I can't set the label's text programmatically (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net

I've seen many possible solutions to this problem, but none of them seems to work.

```
Try
            Dim ricevuto As String
            ricevuto = SerialPort1.ReadExisting

            If String.Compare(ricevuto.Substring(ricevuto.Length - 3), "OF") = 0 Then
                Me.Label1.Text = "aperto"
                Me.Label1.Refresh()
            ElseIf String.Compare(ricevuto.Substring(ricevuto.Length - 3), "ON") = 0 Then
                Me.Label1.Text = "chiuso"
                Me.Label1.Update()

            End If




        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
```

this is the code, but the Label1 doesn't change.

UPDATE: the error is "cross thread operation not valid"

Comment: One important point that no one has mentioned is the fact that the `SerialPort` class raises its `DataReceived` event on a thread pool thread. This is done so that your UI doesn't freeze every time you receive data. That's the reason that you're executing code on a secondary thread in the first place. As has been suggested, you need to marshal a method call to the UI thread in order to affect the UI. I think that it's safe to say that some or all of the solutions you found would have worked if you had implemented them properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the error is "cross thread operation not valid"

When you're working with multiple threads, and you're no longer on the UI thread, you need to `Invoke` the change:

```
Label1.Invoke(Sub() Label1.Text = "aperto")
```

To show the whole thing:

```vb
Dim ricevuto As String = SerialPort1.ReadExisting()
Dim key As String = ricevuto.Substring(ricevuto.Length - 3)

If String.Compare(key, "OF") = 0 Then
    Label1.Invoke(Sub() Label1.Text = "aperto")
ElseIf String.Compare(key, "ON") = 0 Then
    Label1.Invoke(Sub() Label1.Text = "chiuso")
End If
```